# .NET Entity Framework Code First Migrations - Database connection error

Tags: database, connection, migration, entity

Im building a project that is supposed to have N DataContexts.
I have a web application that will do the steps below in App-Start (Global.asax):

1 - If database does not exist, create.
2 - Update database to the latest migration.

When i run the application for the first time (the database is not created yet) , i get an execption "Cannot open database "DBName" requested by the login. The login failed.
Login failed for user 'sa'."

Ok, so at this moment i check for the databse and it is created, but the __Migrations table is not there.

If i stop the application and run it again, the exception is not thrown and the database is successfully updated.

Ive tried setting persist Security Info in my connection string, but nothing changes.

my code is below:
Global.asax

```
    void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Code that runs on application startup
       Bll.AppStart.Databases.Start();  

    }
```

Calling..

```
namespace BusinessLogicLayer.AppStart
{
/// <summary>
/// Inicialização e Update de versão dos bancos de dados do sistema
/// </summary>
public static class Databases
{
    public static void Start()
    {
        //Iniciar DBCore
        DataBaseStart<DataAccessLayer.DataContexts.Core.Context,
            DataAccessLayer.Migrations.Core.Configuration>();
    }

    #region Inicializar bancos de dados

    private static void DataBaseStart<T, TC>()
        where T : DbContext, new()
        where TC : DbMigrationsConfiguration<T>, new()
    {


        //Atualiza a base de dados com base na configuração do migrations
        try
        {

            var migratorConfig = new TC();
            var dbMigrator = new DbMigrator(migratorConfig);
            dbMigrator.Configuration.AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = false;
            dbMigrator.Update();

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            //Exceção quando cria o banco a primeira vez?


            throw new Exception("Banco de dados criado pela primeira vez. Reinicie a aplicação.");




        }


    }

    #endregion
}
```

}

My Context class.. notice it defines an empty database

```
 public class Context : DbContext
 {

    public Context()
    {
        Database.Connection.ConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["PODBCore"].ConnectionString;

    }
    public Context(string connectionString)
    {
        Database.Connection.ConnectionString = connectionString;

    }





}
```

My migrations configuration class

```
public sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<DataContexts.Core.Context>
{
    public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
        AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = false;
    }

    protected override void Seed(DataContexts.Core.Context context)
    {
        //  This method will be called after migrating to the latest version.

    }
}
```

I have a Initial Migration that defines an empty model

```
public partial class Initial : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
    }
}
```

Just to remember, if i run the aplication twice the database is sucessfully created and updated (i did test with other migrations, creating tables and stuff).
The exception is only thrown the first time the application runs, and the database does not exist.

Ive also tried to call Database.SetInitializer, and context.CreateIfNotExist() before running the migration update code.

Edit:

Ive checked the SQL Server log, basically the application is trying to connect to Initial Catalog specified in the connection string but it does not exist. After the excpetion is thrown, the database is created and online though.

Edit:

It will work if i remove the Initial Catalog  property, but then i would have all my dataContexts creating tables in the master database.

We could have N server instances and still have some kind of separation between the contexts but im still trying to get one catalog by context in the same SQL instance

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so i found a solution to this.. its not the best of the coded but its working now.

What i had to do was

1. Create a new WCF Services Layer in my project.
2. Move the "Create&Update" database work to a service class.
3. In the business logic layer, consume the service.
4. If the service.DoWork() method fails, try again (as i said before, it works the second time)

Here is the code in BLL consumig the service

```
using BusinessLogicLayer.WcfServicesLayer.AppStart.Databases;

namespace BusinessLogicLayer.AppStart
{
   /// <summary>
   /// Inicialização e Update de versão dos bancos de dados do sistema
   /// </summary>
   public static class Databases
   {
    public static void Start()
    {
        //Iniciar DBCore
        var client = new DatabasesClient();
        bool databaseStarted = client.DoWork();
        if(!databaseStarted)
        {
            var retry = new DatabasesClient();
            databaseStarted = retry.DoWork();
        }

    }


   }
   }
```

Here is the service class.

```
using System;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;
namespace WcfServicesLayer.AppStart
{
// Serviço de inicialização dos bancos de dados da aplicação
public class Databases : IDatabases
{
    public bool DoWork()
    {
        return StartDatabases();
    }

    private bool StartDatabases()
    {

        //Iniciar DBCore
        return DataBaseStart<DataAccessLayer.DataContexts.Core.Context,
            DataAccessLayer.Migrations.Core.Configuration>();

    }

    private bool DataBaseStart<T, TC>()
        where T : DbContext, new()
        where TC : DbMigrationsConfiguration<T>, new()
    {


        //Atualiza a base de dados com base na configuração do migrations
        try
        {
            var migratorConfig = new TC();
            var dbMigrator = new DbMigrator(migratorConfig);
            dbMigrator.Configuration.AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = false;

            dbMigrator.Update();
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            //Exceção quando cria o banco a primeira vez?
            return false;

        }


    }
}
}
```